# Как подключиться к БД из редактора?

Tags: phpstorm

Весь вопрос в одной картинке по сути:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не правильно? Proxy user и Password ввожу юзера БД и его пароль

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь подключиться к БД через SSH-туннель, т.е. в данном окне нужно вводить имя пользователя и пароль, которые используются для SSH-подключения, а не для подключения к базе данных.